# Alphabetize or remove redundant but slightly different versions of phrases in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, nlp

I have a column with phrases like this:

```
one or more of: 
   word/place name +
   the letter 's' (or the plural version of the word)
in addition to possibly preposition or conjunctions between each word (in, and, etc.)
```

I want to select all the rows that have pluralized or conjunctivized versions of phrases that already exist in the table for deletion/editing. I can get a list of every conjunction/preposition word for matching.

For example, in a table with text rows:

- rabbits and foxes
- apple on plate
- apples plates
- the microsoft eggplant hunters
- fox rabbit
- apple plate
- microsoft hunter eggplant
- chickens

I would want to end up selecting the top 4 rows, essentially taking each row and checking it against the rest of the table to see if it's most basic version already exists.

I could think of a way to regex match the strings themselves but how would I check for the duplicate version? **(This doesnt have to be done in sql I can process the rows with a java program too)**

Comment: This would be a lot easier in a programming language instead of in sql. This is high levels of string manipulation which sql is not designed for. sql is designed to retrieve data and it does that quite well. Pattern matching and that sort of stuff is not efficient. Can you use CLR in your environment. This would be a good time for that.

Comment: Specifically what I am thinking you will need to do is parse the row into individual words, then for each word determine if it is plural. Not really sure what your actual objective is though. Given the 6 rows of data you provided what would you want as output?

Comment: Oh I realize that, the answer doesn't have to be done in sql if there's a simple solution in another language

Comment: @SeanLange given the 6 rows I want the id of the top 3 rows as output (or just the text is fine too since I could match on them)

Comment: So in addition to checking singular and plural you want to remove certain basic words like "the", "and", "on"? Do you have a list of those words you want removed? I am not totally sure why you want the top three rows. What if the 5th row was apples plate? We need to know all the business rules here.

Comment: @SeanLange yes I could create a list. Let's pretend it's just "the" "and" and "on". If it's not a complete match to a pluralized/conjunctivized phrase it doesnt matter. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do grammatical analysis using Regex and certainly not in SQL. What you need is a tool for stemming and morphological analysis like Hunspell. Hunspell is an open source project. I was designed for the Hungarian language, but dictionaries for a lot of other languages are available for Hunspell. You can use it from a lot of different languages and environments.

Project homepage:
http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I wouldn't say that you can't do it, I would however totally agree that t-sql is not where it should be done. It would be horrible inefficient to say the least.

Comment: Hunspell alone won't do it; however, it can remove endings due to plurals, past tenses etc. (stemming) and can tell you whether a word is a noun, a verb etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a stemmer/lemmatizer and remove the items from the original list based on the stems/lemmas.

First let's see what happens if you stem the list:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import stopwords
>>> from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
>>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

>>> stoplist = stopwords.words('english')
>>> wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> porter = PorterStemmer()

>>> text = """rabbits and foxes
... apple on plate
... apples plates
... the microsoft eggplant hunters
... fox rabbit
... apple plate
... microsoft hunter eggplant
... chickens"""
>>> text = [i.split() for i in text.split('\n')]
>>> text
[['rabbits', 'and', 'foxes'], ['apple', 'on', 'plate'], ['apples', 'plates'], ['the', 'microsoft', 'eggplant', 'hunters'], ['fox', 'rabbit'], ['apple', 'plate'], ['microsoft', 'hunter', 'eggplant'], ['chickens']]

# Using stemmer
>>> stemmed_text = [[porter.stem(j) for j in i] for i in text]
>>> stemmed_text
[[u'rabbit', u'and', u'fox'], [u'appl', u'on', u'plate'], [u'appl', u'plate'], [u'the', u'microsoft', u'eggplant', u'hunter'], [u'fox', u'rabbit'], [u'appl', u'plate'], [u'microsoft', u'hunter', u'eggplant'], [u'chicken']]
>>> stemmed_text_wo_stops = [[porter.stem(j) for j in i if j not in stoplist] for i in text]
>>> stemmed_text_wo_stops 
[[u'rabbit', u'fox'], [u'appl', u'plate'], [u'appl', u'plate'], [u'microsoft', u'eggplant', u'hunter'], [u'fox', u'rabbit'], [u'appl', u'plate'], [u'microsoft', u'hunter', u'eggplant'], [u'chicken']]
```

To lemmatize, do this instead of stem:

```
# Using lemmatizer.
>>> lemmatized_text = [[wnl.lemmatize(j) for j in i] for i in text]
>>> lemmatized_text
[[u'rabbit', 'and', u'fox'], ['apple', 'on', 'plate'], [u'apple', u'plate'], ['the', 'microsoft', 'eggplant', u'hunter'], ['fox', 'rabbit'], ['apple', 'plate'], ['microsoft', 'hunter', 'eggplant'], [u'chicken']]
>>> lemmatized_text_wo_stops = [[wnl.lemmatize(j) for j in i if j not in stoplist] for i in text]
>>> lemmatized_text_wo_stops 
[[u'rabbit', u'fox'], ['apple', 'plate'], [u'apple', u'plate'], ['microsoft', 'eggplant', u'hunter'], ['fox', 'rabbit'], ['apple', 'plate'], ['microsoft', 'hunter', 'eggplant'], [u'chicken']]
```

Then you can remove the items from the original list as such:

```
# Remove duplicate based on stems
>>> already_in_list = [] # To keep track of items
>>> deduplicated_list = []
>>> for stem, original in zip(stemmed_text_wo_stops, text):
...     if stem in already_in_list:
...             continue
...     else:
...             already_in_list.append(stem)
...             deduplicated_list.append(original)
... 
>>> deduplicated_wordlist = [" ".join(i) for i in deduplicated_list]
>>> print '\n'.join(deduplicated_wordlist)
rabbits and foxes
apple on plate
the microsoft eggplant hunters
fox rabbit
microsoft hunter eggplant
chickens

# Using lemmatizer.
>>> lemmatized_text = [[wnl.lemmatize(j) for j in i] for i in text]
>>> lemmatized_text
[[u'rabbit', 'and', u'fox'], ['apple', 'on', 'plate'], [u'apple', u'plate'], ['the', 'microsoft', 'eggplant', u'hunter'], ['fox', 'rabbit'], ['apple', 'plate'], ['microsoft', 'hunter', 'eggplant'], [u'chicken']]
>>> lemmatized_text_wo_stops = [[wnl.lemmatize(j) for j in i if j not in stoplist] for i in text]
>>> lemmatized_text_wo_stops 
[[u'rabbit', u'fox'], ['apple', 'plate'], [u'apple', u'plate'], ['microsoft', 'eggplant', u'hunter'], ['fox', 'rabbit'], ['apple', 'plate'], ['microsoft', 'hunter', 'eggplant'], [u'chicken']]
>>> # Remove duplicate based on lemmas
... already_in_list = [] # To keep track of items
>>> deduplicated_list = []
>>> for lemma, original in zip(lemmatized_text_wo_stops, text):
...     if lemma in already_in_list:
...             continue
...     else:
...             already_in_list.append(lemma)
...             deduplicated_list.append(original)
... 
>>> deduplicated_wordlist = [" ".join(i) for i in deduplicated_list]
>>> print '\n'.join(deduplicated_wordlist)
rabbits and foxes
apple on plate
the microsoft eggplant hunters
fox rabbit
microsoft hunter eggplant
chickens
```

But there's still so issues with regards to order of the words, so let's do some intermediate sorting:

```
# Let's do some sorting in-between.
>>> lemmatized_text = [[wnl.lemmatize(j) for j in i] for i in text]
>>> lemmatized_text
[[u'rabbit', 'and', u'fox'], ['apple', 'on', 'plate'], [u'apple', u'plate'], ['the', 'microsoft', 'eggplant', u'hunter'], ['fox', 'rabbit'], ['apple', 'plate'], ['microsoft', 'hunter', 'eggplant'], [u'chicken']]
>>> lemmatized_text_wo_stops = [sorted([wnl.lemmatize(j) for j in i if j not in stoplist]) for i in text]
>>> lemmatized_text_wo_stops 
[[u'fox', u'rabbit'], ['apple', 'plate'], [u'apple', u'plate'], ['eggplant', u'hunter', 'microsoft'], ['fox', 'rabbit'], ['apple', 'plate'], ['eggplant', 'hunter', 'microsoft'], [u'chicken']]
>>> 
>>> # Remove duplicate based on lemmas
... already_in_list = [] # To keep track of items
>>> deduplicated_list = []
>>> for lemma, original in zip(lemmatized_text_wo_stops, text):
...     if lemma in already_in_list:
...             continue
...     else:
...             already_in_list.append(lemma)
...             deduplicated_list.append(original)
... 
>>> deduplicated_wordlist = [" ".join(i) for i in deduplicated_list]
>>> print '\n'.join(deduplicated_wordlist)
rabbits and foxes
apple on plate
the microsoft eggplant hunters
chickens
```

Here's the full code:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import stopwords
>>> from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
>>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

>>> stoplist = stopwords.words('english')
>>> wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> porter = PorterStemmer()

>>> text = """rabbits and foxes
... apple on plate
... apples plates
... the microsoft eggplant hunters
... fox rabbit
... apple plate
... microsoft hunter eggplant
... chickens"""
>>> text = [i.split() for i in text.split('\n')]
>>> text
[['rabbits', 'and', 'foxes'], ['apple', 'on', 'plate'], ['apples', 'plates'], ['the', 'microsoft', 'eggplant', 'hunters'], ['fox', 'rabbit'], ['apple', 'plate'], ['microsoft', 'hunter', 'eggplant'], ['chickens']]

# Using stemmer
>>> stemmed_text = [[porter.stem(j) for j in i] for i in text]
>>> stemmed_text
[[u'rabbit', u'and', u'fox'], [u'appl', u'on', u'plate'], [u'appl', u'plate'], [u'the', u'microsoft', u'eggplant', u'hunter'], [u'fox', u'rabbit'], [u'appl', u'plate'], [u'microsoft', u'hunter', u'eggplant'], [u'chicken']]
>>> stemmed_text_wo_stops = [[porter.stem(j) for j in i if j not in stoplist] for i in text]
>>> stemmed_text_wo_stops 
[[u'rabbit', u'fox'], [u'appl', u'plate'], [u'appl', u'plate'], [u'microsoft', u'eggplant', u'hunter'], [u'fox', u'rabbit'], [u'appl', u'plate'], [u'microsoft', u'hunter', u'eggplant'], [u'chicken']]

# Remove duplicate based on stems
>>> already_in_list = [] # To keep track of items
>>> deduplicated_list = []
>>> for stem, original in zip(stemmed_text_wo_stops, text):
...     if stem in already_in_list:
...             continue
...     else:
...             already_in_list.append(stem)
...             deduplicated_list.append(original)
... 
>>> deduplicated_wordlist = [" ".join(i) for i in deduplicated_list]
>>> print '\n'.join(deduplicated_wordlist)
rabbits and foxes
apple on plate
the microsoft eggplant hunters
fox rabbit
microsoft hunter eggplant
chickens

# Using lemmatizer.
>>> lemmatized_text = [[wnl.lemmatize(j) for j in i] for i in text]
>>> lemmatized_text
[[u'rabbit', 'and', u'fox'], ['apple', 'on', 'plate'], [u'apple', u'plate'], ['the', 'microsoft', 'eggplant', u'hunter'], ['fox', 'rabbit'], ['apple', 'plate'], ['microsoft', 'hunter', 'eggplant'], [u'chicken']]
>>> lemmatized_text_wo_stops = [[wnl.lemmatize(j) for j in i if j not in stoplist] for i in text]
>>> lemmatized_text_wo_stops 
[[u'rabbit', u'fox'], ['apple', 'plate'], [u'apple', u'plate'], ['microsoft', 'eggplant', u'hunter'], ['fox', 'rabbit'], ['apple', 'plate'], ['microsoft', 'hunter', 'eggplant'], [u'chicken']]
>>> # Remove duplicate based on lemmas
... already_in_list = [] # To keep track of items
>>> deduplicated_list = []
>>> for lemma, original in zip(lemmatized_text_wo_stops, text):
...     if lemma in already_in_list:
...             continue
...     else:
...             already_in_list.append(lemma)
...             deduplicated_list.append(original)
... 
>>> deduplicated_wordlist = [" ".join(i) for i in deduplicated_list]
>>> print '\n'.join(deduplicated_wordlist)
rabbits and foxes
apple on plate
the microsoft eggplant hunters
fox rabbit
microsoft hunter eggplant
chickens

# Let's do some sorting in-between.
>>> lemmatized_text = [[wnl.lemmatize(j) for j in i] for i in text]
>>> lemmatized_text
[[u'rabbit', 'and', u'fox'], ['apple', 'on', 'plate'], [u'apple', u'plate'], ['the', 'microsoft', 'eggplant', u'hunter'], ['fox', 'rabbit'], ['apple', 'plate'], ['microsoft', 'hunter', 'eggplant'], [u'chicken']]
>>> lemmatized_text_wo_stops = [sorted([wnl.lemmatize(j) for j in i if j not in stoplist]) for i in text]
>>> lemmatized_text_wo_stops 
[[u'fox', u'rabbit'], ['apple', 'plate'], [u'apple', u'plate'], ['eggplant', u'hunter', 'microsoft'], ['fox', 'rabbit'], ['apple', 'plate'], ['eggplant', 'hunter', 'microsoft'], [u'chicken']]
>>> 
>>> # Remove duplicate based on lemmas
... already_in_list = [] # To keep track of items
>>> deduplicated_list = []
>>> for lemma, original in zip(lemmatized_text_wo_stops, text):
...     if lemma in already_in_list:
...             continue
...     else:
...             already_in_list.append(lemma)
...             deduplicated_list.append(original)
... 
>>> deduplicated_wordlist = [" ".join(i) for i in deduplicated_list]
>>> print '\n'.join(deduplicated_wordlist)
rabbits and foxes
apple on plate
the microsoft eggplant hunters
chickens
```

Comment: BTW, the above code is in python and using NLTK library. If you're using any other language, just replace the lemmatizer/stemmer with anything you can find.

Comment: is there a stemmer that works for location names? preferably in java